# setValue wouldn't work just before submitting(react hook form)

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Set the value just before submission, but `setValue("name", name)` wouldn't set the value on React Hook Form correctly... I've tried to use `async`, but it still wouldn't work at all.

I tried to use the react hook form to save the data. However, setValue did not work.

```
  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(
    async (data) => {
      await setValue("name", name)
      // data.name is undefined
      submitPost(data)
    },
    (err: any) => {
      toast.error(err.message)
    },
  )
```

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: I tried to use the react hook form to save the data. However, setValue did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const onSubmit = (data) => { 

      let newdata = {
          ...data,
          parameter_name: value_to_set
        }
      submitPost(newdata)
      
}
```

Comment: Make sense! Thank you so much!!