# React hook form setValue null not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, setvalue

I am trying to use react hook form setValue to set every value that is equal to an empty string to null, but it doesnt work.

Any fixes?

```
const onSubmit = data => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {

      if (value === '') {
        setValue(key, null)
      }
    }
(Method here for sending data to api)
    reset();
  }
}
```

Edit:

I found this workaround for my issue:

```
const onSubmit = data => {
    let newData = data;

    Object.keys(newData).forEach((field) => {
      if (newData[field] === '') {
        newData[field] = null
      }
    })
    /Method for api here
    reset();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code ?

Comment: Hello, I edited my original post with the code that is run on submit.

Comment: Add a console.log before the setValue method and see if it is printing out first

Comment: It prints out all the keys with values = '', but it doesnt seem to register the changes before submitting data to the api

Comment: How is onSubmit called? What calls it? Can it be that "data" isn't what you expect it to be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266620/setvalue-wouldnt-work-just-before-submittingreact-hook-form?rq=2 I found someone with a similar issue and in the mean time I also found a temporary workaround.

Comment: There's a lot of code missing here. What is not working?

Comment: setValue from React Hook Form does not update the values that fit the criteria before the submitted data gets sent to the api.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `setValue` is one of your hook, that you created like this:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState();
```

Then you can't use multiple `setValue`, I mean, if you use:

```js
setValue("toto");
setValue("tata");
setValue("titi");
```

in one function, then `value` will change only **once**, to the last value (here "titi").

so you need to change `value` type to an array / object and perform only 1 `setValue` with the modified object, like:

```js
const array = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => value === '' ? null : value);
setValue(array);
```

Comment: Hey, setValue is a function from React Hook Form to update formState. I got it working, but thanks anyways :)

Comment: @coderman123 Yeah I know it's a basic function and you know how to use it, I think you missed the main point of my post because it was not a tutorial about "how to use setValue", but an explanation of "don't use setValue in loop because only the last value will be set, you can perfrom 1000 setValue() in your useState or function, but only the last one will be performed